# How do two unequal `Uint8Array`s influence each other when constructed from an `ArrayBuffer`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, instance, arraybuffer, uint8array

I have an `ArrayBuffer`, and I want to get two separate `Uint8Array` copies from it. I attempt this by using the `Uint8Array` constructor on the `ArrayBuffer` twice. The constructed array instances do not equal. Yet, when you alter one, it alters the other in the same way. How is this possible, and why would this be the case?

[image: Unequal arrays magically influencing each other]

On the other hand, if you construct new `Uint8Array`s *from* the constructed `Uint8Array`, they will be functionally separated as one would expect.

[image: Unequal arrays working properly]

Comment: It would be better if you could shorten your example array and include the code you're using in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) which allows the use of `console.log` to show the intermediate results.

Comment: But for this, `array1 === array2` is doing a reference check, and since `array1` and `array2` are different instances of the `Uint8Array` class, the result is false.

Comment: That's the point! If they are different arrays, how can they influence each other when their contents are altered? This functionality typically only occurs when two variables use the same instance.

Comment: Because they reference the same buffer.

Comment: They reference a buffer? I thought they were just `Uint8Array`s, like any other. How is there some intrinsic reference?

Comment: It's common to `TypedArray`s. See [MDN's docs on the `buffer` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/buffer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries inside of a TypedArray are actually stored in the underlying buffer, if you get/set the array, it reads/writes to/from the buffer. If you create a TypedArray from another TypedArray, the underlying buffer will be copied, and therefore the arrays will not be linked.

```
 array.buffer === array1.buffer // true
 array1.buffer === array2.buffer // false
```